# How can I find the PID for software where the name of the software is different from the executable?

Tags: command-line, process, .desktop

I run "Videos" software from the Dash in Ubuntu. After some minutes the software freezes.

I've tried searching for the PID of the software to kill it, but I can't find any result with these commands:

```
pgrep Videos

ps -eo cmd,pid,stime
```

I don't know the `stime` of the process.

I have to restart my computer and after login, I see the software is executed by `totem` command.

How can I find the PID for software where the name of the software is different from that of the executable file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a command from terminal then the command will always show up in the process table being a process.

Your case is different as you have run a Desktop entry (declared in a `.desktop` file), whose name and the command it executes can be totally different.

The `.desktop` files use an INI format to express metadata.

Here is the Desktop entry for `htop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Htop
Type=Application
Comment=Show System Processes
Terminal=true
Exec=htop
Icon=htop
Categories=ConsoleOnly;System;
GenericName=Process Viewer
```

In you case, the `Name` is `Videos` and the `Exec` line will indicate the actual command executed.

---

You should track down the `.desktop` file and check the entry to get the command actually being executed.

So lets find the `.desktop` file that contains `Name=Videos`:

```
% grep -RH '^Name=Videos$' ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/totem.desktop:Name=Videos
```

Got it !!

It's declared in `/usr/share/applications/totem.desktop`.

Now let's check what command it actually runs:

```
% cat /usr/share/applications/totem.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Videos
Comment=Play movies
Keywords=Video;Movie;Film;Clip;Series;Player;DVD;TV;Disc;
Exec=totem %U
Icon=totem
Terminal=false
Type=Application
.
.
<truncated>
```

As you can see, the `Exec` key says `totem %U`. `%U` indicates a list of URIs.

---

Now, if you do:

```
pgrep totem
```

you would get the PID of the `totem` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The default video player of `Ubuntu` is `totem`, so if you want to find the `PID` of the  Video player, you should find the `totem` process. You can do like this:

`ps aux | grep totem`, then you can kill the `PID` of `totem`.
And you can get the information in [SoundVideoDefault](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundVideoDefault)